# Perl - Convert MSSQL Image string to JPEG/PNG using Perl

Tags: image, perl

Without having to use Image::Magick;, is there a way to output to the local file system an MSSQL Image string as a JPEG/PNG file.

The following in C# works very well, struggling to find the equivalent in Perl.

```
     string base64string = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QB...";  # This string shortened otherwise it would not fit
       byte[] blob = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
       File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\image.jpg", blob);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you just need [decode_base64](http://perldoc.perl.org/MIME/Base64.html) on your string. Then write it to the file opened with 'wb'.

Comment: Ivan,  you know what is crazy, I tried that earlier,  just tried it again and it worked....thanks for making me revisit..not sure why the image was not visible last time.     use MIME::Base64 ();
     $decoded = MIME::Base64::decode($image_ref);

Comment: @user2574678 Select Ivan's answer as your solution when you have a chance to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need [decode_base64](http://perldoc.perl.org/MIME/Base64.html) on your string. Then write it to the file opened with `>` and run [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) on handler. So your data will not be corrupted by new line character conversion.